# How to make windows create associations with certain filetypes when developing in python

Tags: python, windows, associations

I am making an mp3 player and in Windows, usually applications are launched depending on file type which I call file association. For example MP3 files are automatically associated to open in groove. How can I make this happen for applications I make in python. Is this an operating system setting or variable that assigns these?

Comment: Read https://ss64.com/nt/assoc.html and https://ss64.com/nt/ftype.html

Comment: Thanks this gave me a good understanding for the record I use assoc to assign the filetypes to names then ftype from name to application?

Comment: First, use `ftype` to create the link between a FileType and an executable program. Then, apply `assoc` (always check `ftype` for newly named your own (temporary) filetype before creating). See **Examples** at https://ss64.com/nt/ftype.html

Comment: Thank you so much that makes much more sense!